# Angularjs Page Reload/ Refresh give Error 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: angularjs

I use angularjs 1.6 for my project when I refresh the page it gives  me an error **500 Internal Server Error** **nginx** I used

```
<base href="/" />
```

in index.html file also I include config.js file

```
'use strict';

abc.config(['$ocLazyLoadProvider', 'localStorageServiceProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
function ($ocLazyLoadProvider, localStorageServiceProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('chasebid');

    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        debug: false,
        events: true,
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    // $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        // enabled: true,
        // requireBase: false
    // });


    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'angular_view/Index/indexbody.html',
        controller: 'indexBodyController',
        resolve: {
            loadMyFile: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'abc',
                    files: ['angular_project_file/controllers/indexBodyController.min.js']

                })
            }
        } // END state
    }).state('aboutus', {
        url: '/about_us',
        templateUrl: 'angular_view/aboutus/aboutus.html',

    }).state('details', {
        url: '/details:detailsId',
        templateUrl: 'angular_view/details/details.html',
        controller: 'auctionDetailsController',
        resolve: {
            loadMyFile: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'abc',
                    files: ['angular_project_file/controllers/DetailsController.min.js']

                })
            }
        } // END  state
    }).state('buy', {
        url: '/buy',
        templateUrl: 'angular_view/buy/buy.html',
        controller: 'buyController',
        resolve: {
            loadMyFile: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'abc',
                    files: ['angular_project_file/controllers/buyController.min.js']
                })
            }
        } // END state
    }).state('contactus', {
        url: '/contact_us',
        templateUrl: 'angular_view/contactus/contactus.html',

    }).state('faq', {
        url: '/FAQ',
        templateUrl: 'angular_view/faq/faq.html',

    }).state('freeauctions', {
        url: '/free_auctions',
        templateUrl: 'angular_view/free_auctions/free.html',
        controller: 'freeController',
        resolve: {
            loadMyFile: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'abc',

                    files: ['angular_project_file/controllers/freeController.min.js']
                })
            }
        } // END state
    ;





}])
```

when i refresh page it state not load what is the issue because in localhost it work fine but in production server it give me error like 
**500 Internal Server Error nginx**

Comment: A 500 Internal Server Error indicates that your backend has troubles, not angularjs itself.

Comment: @MarcusHöglund I didn't get what you meant by Backend has troubles, can you please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: The 500 code is for situation where your client communicates with a backend service (api, web service etc) and that service hits an unexpected exception. then the service returns a 500 to the client. So, look for your client communications with the backend service you are using. This error could be from there

Comment: @MarcusHöglund Our API and Backend work fine issue is when we reload or refresh or Ctrl +F5 then give me that error basically page loss there a state in angular js 1.6 so for I use https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UeNbiSX_dkQ this video as reference

Comment: Probably when you refresh the page your client is calling the backend in a way that was not anticipiated by whoever wrote the backend code, causing it to crash (500 error). You will need to look at the logs/source for the backend to fix this most likely.

Comment: haw to fix this issue please ??